Relationship between BCH code and asymmetric Ramanujan bipartite graph ( possibility for a research collaboration)
I have been working on a research topic that deals with the binary matrices arising from the BCH codes by selecting code vectors of specific weight while discarding the rest of the code vectors that have undesired weight. Through simulation I found that these matrices are actually the biadjacency matrices of the Ramanujan bipartite graph.
I begin detailing the Ramanujan bipartite graph here:
The full adjacency matrix $A\in\{0,1\}^{n \times n}$ of a bipartite graph looks like
$$A = \left[\begin{array}{ c | c }
    0 & B \\
    \hline
    B^{\top} & 0
  \end{array}\right],$$
where $B$ is called the biadjacency matrix associated with the graph. Now, if $B$ is $d_r, d_c$ regular then it means that every row of $B$ contains exactly $d_r$ number of $1's$ and every column contains exactly $d_c$ number of $1's$.
Now, let $B$ is a $n_r \times n_c$ matrix. Define, $p:= \min \{n_r,n_c\}$. Let $ \sigma_1 \geq \sigma_2 \geq ...\geq \sigma_p \geq 0$ denote the singular values of $B$. Then the graph is said to be asymmetric Ramanujan bipartite graph if
$$\sigma_{2} \leq \sqrt{d_r - 1} + \sqrt{d_c - 1}.\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$ It is obvious that
$\sigma_1 = \sqrt{d_r d_c}$.
Now, I come to the BCH codes I am working with. Let $f(m):\mathbb{Z}^+ \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^{+}_{even}$ is a function from the set of positive integer to the set positive even integer. Then by the $[f(m)-1]$-BCH code I mean the BCH code with designed distance $f(m)-1$ and code length $2^m - 1$. Whereas by $[f(m)]$-BCH code I mean the BCH code that consists of all the even parity code vectors of a given $[f(m)-1]$-BCH code.
Now, I come to the specific of types of the BCH codes I am dealing with.
$\textbf{Theorem 1:}$ For an even integer $m \geq 4$, define
$$
  w_1= 2^{m -1} - 2^{m/2 - 1},\ 
  w_2= 2^{m - 1}, \ 
  w_3= 2^{m -1} + 2^{m/2 - 1}.
  $$
Let $a_j$ denote the total number of code vector of weight $j$ in a given         binary linear code. Then, a  $[2^{m-1} - 2^{m/2 - 1} ]$-BCH code has the
following weight distribution:
\begin{align*}
   & a_0 = 1, \\
   & a_{w_1} = (2^{m - 1} + 2^{m/2 -1}) (2^{m/2} - 1),\\
   & a_{w_2} = 2^{m} - 1,\\
   & a_{w_3} = (2^{m - 1} - 2^{m/2 -1}) (2^{m/2} - 1),\\
   & a_j = 0,\ \mbox{for other values of}\  j .
  \end{align*}
The above theorem is a known result by T.Kasami.
Now, let $B$ denote the matrix consisting of all the code vectors of weight $w_1$.
Then it is obvious that for $B$, $d_c = w_1$. Now, using the simulations I have found that $d_r$ is always given by
$$ d_r = \frac{a_{w_1}w_1}{2^m - 1}.\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (2)$$
Note: I don't know how to derive equation (2) which seems very challenging to me.
Now, as a consequence of $\textbf{Theorem 1}$, the inner product between two distinct columns of $B$ can only be one of these three values: $ 2^{m - 2} - 2^{m/2 -2},\  2^{m - 2} - 2^{m/2 - 1},\  2^{m - 2} - 3 \cdot 2^{m/2 - 2}.$
Again using the simulations, I found that the $\sigma_2$ of $B$ always satisfies inequality $(1)$. For example, for $m = 4$, we have $\sigma_2 = 3.464$, for $m = 6$, we have $\sigma_2 = 10.583$, for $m = 8$, we have $\sigma_2 = 30.983$, for $m = 10$, we have $\sigma_2 = 89.084$.
Now, I come to the other type of BCH code I am dealing with. The next theorem is also a known result from T.Kasami.
$\textbf{Theorem 2:}$  For an odd integer $ m\geq 3$, define
$$
  w_1= 2^{m -1} - 2^{(m + 1)/2 -1},\ 
  w_2= 2^{m - 1},
  w_3 = 2^{m - 1} + 2^{(m + 1)/2 - 1}. 
  $$
Then, a $[2^{m-1}- 2^{(m-1)/2}]$-BCH code
has the following distribution:
\begin{align*}
   &  a_0 =1,\\
   &  a_{w_1} = 
   (2^{m - 2} + 2^{(m - 1)/2 -1}) (2^{m} - 1),\\
   &  a_{w_2}  = (2^{m}- 2^{m - 1 } + 1) (2^{m} - 1),\\
   & a_{w_3}  = 
   (2^{m - 2} - 2^{(m - 1)/2 -1}) (2^{m} - 1),\\
   &  a_j = 0,\ \mbox{for other values of $j$.}
  \end{align*}
Now, let $B$ denote the matrix consisting of all the code vectors of weight $w_2$.
Then it is obvious that for $B$, $d_c = w_2$. Now, using the simulations I have found that $d_r$ is always given by
$$ d_r = \frac{a_{w_2}w_2}{2^m - 1}.\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (3)$$
Again, I don't know how to derive equation $(3)$.
Now, as a consequence of $\textbf{Theorem 2}$, the inner product between two distinct columns of $B$ can only be one of these three values: $ 2^{m -2} + 2^{(m + 1)/2 -2},\ 2^{m - 2},\ 2^{m -2} - 2^{(m + 1)/2 -2}.$
Again using the simulations, I found that the $\sigma_2$ of $B$ always satisfies inequality $(1)$. For example, for $m = 5$, we have $\sigma_2 = 11.66$, for $m = 7$, we have $\sigma_2 = 45.6$.
So, the simulation results are telling me that the matrices $B$ obtained from the BCH code are biadjacency matrix of a Ramanujan bipartite graph but proof by simulation is not a proof. I need to prove it mathematically which boils down to proving equations $(2)$ and $(3)$ in addition to proving $\sigma_2$ satisfies the inequality $(1)$. I have read the books on the spectral analysis of graphs but that did not help me in my case.

I may be missing something, but the argument below should work:
The words of weight $2^{m-1}$ of your code are maximal length sequences of period $2^m-1,$ in fact, phases of the same sequence.
Such a sequence is represented by the trace expression
$$
(tr(\theta \alpha^k): 0\leq k\leq 2^m-2)
$$
where the choice of $\theta \neq 0,$ gives the shift or the phase, and $\alpha$ is a primitive element of $GF(2^m).$
Put together those sequences in an array, there are $a_{w_2}$ of them and being the shifts of the same sequence, the distribution of the 1's is uniform across all positions. Take the total number of 1's in the array and divide by the number of positions, i.e., $2^m-1$ to obtain (3).
The vectors of weight $w_1$ are also phases (shifts) of a given sequence, this can be observed e.g. from Magma, and a similar argument applies there as well giving (2).
You can use Berlekamp Massey algorithm to determine the linear recurrence that those vectors satisfy. The trace expression will be a bit more complicated probably.
References: Helleseth and Kumar, "Sequences with Low Correlation", Handbook of Coding Theory. Also papers by Charpin et al may have the exact trace expression for the sequences of weight $w_1.$
Magma calculator is available online here, and you can use the expression BCH(GF(2), 2^m-1, DesignDistance) to obtain the code and query its various properties.

Thanks for your insight into the problem. I am able to prove $(2)$ and $(3)$. However, I am not able to follow you on how I can mathematically derive $
(1)$?

Hi, I shouldn't post that late at night. I meant to type (3) not (1).

Unfortunately I can't get my hands on the the book which you have mentioned in reference. Could you please direct me to the sources where I can read about how the maximal length sequence of period $2^m - 1$ for odd $m$ with three-valued cross correlation are generated?

the code-words of weight $2^{m-1}$ for odd $m \geq 3$ in my question are actually the different phase shifts of total $2^{m-1}+1$ unique $m$-sequences of period $2^{m}-1$ with three-valued cross-correlation. Could you please help me in finding the study materials where I can find the exact cross-correlation distribution for the $m$-sequence with three-valued cross-correlation.

Hi, I am looking for my softcopy of that chapter by Helleseth and Kumar but have changed machines, so no success. Have been busy. You may also try https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1455966 "Crosscorrelation Properties of Pseudorandom Sequences" by Pursley and Sarwate. Or the book by Gong and Golomb on Sequences, google it.

Thanks for giving me the direction. In my another question (link given in next comment box) you have told me that not all the sequences obtained from the set of codewords of weight $2^{m-1}$ are maximal length sequence. However, in your answer to this present question, you have written that  "The words of weight $2^{m-1}$ of your code are maximal length sequences of period  {2^{m}-1}", and this is confusing me. Could you please shed some light on what you actually meant by aforementioned statement in your answer to my this present question?

Link to the another question
