Probability - Find the expected number of item throws into N containers until one of the container reaches k items
There are $N$ empty containers, which are unlabeled and are exactly the same. Each time, with equal probability, a ball is throwed into a random container.
Q: What is the expected number of throws $f(k, N)$ until one of the containers reaches a number of $k$ balls?
If we cannot find the exact expression for $f(k, N)$, can we at least find a bound as strict as possible?

For what it's worth, virtually every MathSE posted question that I have seen, that followed this article on MathSE protocol has been upvoted rather than downvoted.  I am not necessarily advocating this protocol.  Instead, I am merely stating a fact: if you scrupulously follow the linked article, skipping/omitting nothing, you virtually guarantee a positive response.

Coupon collector problem (look it up) states that it takes on average $N H_N\sim N \log N$ throws to ensure each bin has at least one ball. By that time, the max load is at least the average load, i.e., $\geq c \log N.$ This solves the problem for $k \leq c \log N.$
More generally, "Balls into bins:a simple and tight analysis" by Raab and Steger from M. Luby, J. Rolim, and M. Serna (Eds.): RANDOM’98, LNCS 1518, pp. 159-170, 1998, shows that when $k$ balls are thrown uniformly into $N$ bins the maximum load behaves differently in different regimes. If $ N/\mathrm{polylog(N)}<k<c N \log N$ then the max load is roughly
$$
\log N/\log(N \log N/k).
$$
The case $k=c N \log N$ was mentioned above. For larger $k,$ the max load is equal to the average load $k/N$ with a correction term, something like
$$
\frac{k}{N}+\sqrt{\frac{2k \log N}{N}}
$$
See the paper for details. It can be found online.

Can you see this question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4946834/relationship-between-bch-code-and-asymmetric-ramanujan-bipartite-graph-possibi
