How to find the generator matrix for $C/C^{\perp}$?
Background/my workings:
I am reading a paper which talks about the $[6,5,2]$ classical binary single parity-check code $C$.
I understand that from the given parameters we can find its parity check matrix $H$.

$H$ has $d-1=1$ linearly independent column
$H$ has dimensions $(n-k) \times n = 1 \times 6$

So $H$ must be $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$.
$H$, in standard form, has the form $[-A^{T}|I_{n-k}]$. From $H$, We can obtain the generator matrix $G=[I_{k}|A]$.
As such, $G=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$

Information from the paper:
However, the paper states the following:
The $[6,5,2]$ classical binary single parity-check code $C$ is generated by: $$G_{C} = \begin{bmatrix} H_{C} \\ G_{C/C^{\perp}} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$  which is the same as the generator matrix $G$ (obtained by standard form method) if you put it into RREF.

My question:
I know that the rows of $G_{C/C^{\perp}}$ generate all coset representatives of $C^{\perp}$ in $C$. However, I don't understand how this $G_{C/C^{\perp}}$ was found. From the paper, $G_{C/C^{\perp}}$ is $$G_{C/C^{\perp}}= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$.
However, I would have thought that the coset representatives would just have been the rows of the generators matrix $G$ added to the codewords of $C^{\perp} =$ {{ $ 1,1,1,1,1,1$},{$0,0,0,0,0,0$}}. However, when you row reduce the $10$ resulting vectors, you get $G$ instead of $G_{C/C^{\perp}}$.
How is this $G_{C/C^{\perp}}$ matrix found?

$C^\perp$, a $[6,1,6]$ code, has $32$ cosets, $16$ of which have only even-weight vectors while the other $16$ cosets have only odd-weight vectors.

Begin Edit: To answer the numerous questions raised by the OP in the comments, each coset consists of two vectors, not just one vector as the OP seems to believe, the cosets are disjoint,and the $32$ cosets constitute a partition  of the vector space of dimension $6$ over the binary field into $32$ disjoint sets. Furthermore, since $C$ is the set of all binary vectors of even weight, and both codewords of $C^\perp$ happen to have even weight, it is reasonable to assert that $C^\perp \subset C$ without having to prove this fact in great detail.  End Edit

Since $C^\perp \subset C$, $C^\perp$ has $16$ cosets that contain codewords in $C$ only. These are the $16$ cosets that have even-weight weight vectors only. The other $16$ cosets of $C^\perp$ contain vectors of odd Hamming weight and are not codewords in $C$ (or in $C^\perp$).  So, it is not too surprising that $G_{C/C^\perp}$ has only $4$ rows whose $16$ linear combinations generate these $16$ coset representatives of $C^\perp$ in $C$.

Could you see this question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4946834/relationship-between-bch-code-and-asymmetric-ramanujan-bipartite-graph-possibi

Ah, I see. So the cosets of $C^{\perp}$ consists of  the distinct $q^{n-k} = 2^{6-1}=32$ vectors obtained by adding all binary tuples of length 6 to its codewords $(000000)$ and $(111111)$?

Also, how do we know that $C^{\perp}$ is contained in $C$? i.e. how do we know that $C$ is a self-orthogonal code? Or are we just assuming for the sake of ease that all CSS codes we are considering are self-orthogonal?

Or is the fact the we are generating the quotient group $C/C^{perp}$ which denotes all of the coset representatives of $C^{perp}$ IN $C$? And this implies $C^{\perp} $ is contained in $ C$ ?
